# JPA + MariaDB: how does the collation affect unicode support?

Tags: java, unicode, mariadb

My java service stores stuff in MariaDB (10.3) in database tables, using JPA 3 with EclipseLink as the JPA provider. The database is using encoding `uft8mb4` with default collation `utf8mb4_general_ci`. The RDBMS is configured with `character-set-server = utf8mb4`.

Here's a simple table, mapping to a DAO.

```
CREATE TABLE `directory_entries` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

So far so good. Storing a string in a column `name`, then retrieving the entity again works fine: Unicode characters are stored and fetched.

Now, I discovered that, when querying entries by values in the `name` column, `"A  " == "A"`, unless a *no-pad collation* is used. Switching the collation for the column to `utf8mb4_general_nopad_ci` fixes the whitespace-comparison, but no longer stores unicode characters unmodified: "ü" becomes "Ã¼".

What is going on here? My understanding is the collation only plays a part in *sorting* and *comparing*, not in *storing & fetching*?! How do I store & fetch unicode strings *and* compare them without padding?

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me: Lifting MySQL Connector/J from 8.0.23 to 8.0.27.

From 8.0.26, MySQL changed the way the JDBC driver negotiates unicode handling with the server ([link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html)).